# HTML5 Web sockets (TCP Connection), with flash fallback

Tags: flash, html, websocket

I read about a project that enables the developer to program a HTML5 web sockets application that is compatible with older browsers by automatically falling back to using a flash method.

Can anyone source this, as I can't find details now I'm interested in starting development?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've written a [decent tutorial](http://joshuakehn.com/2010/9/22/WebSocket-Tutorial-with-Nodejs.html) on this.

To summarize:

Include the `web_socket.js` and flash (swf) object on the page and get going. The `web_socket.js` object contains the necessary code to fallback on the FlashSocket if WebSockets are not supported.

If you want to use this in an actual application, you will have to server Flash Policy Files on port 843. I go over that too.

Comment: thanks! I think I may have even been looking for that exact tutorial!

Comment: @Greg: Google hasn't indexed my blog since the old material, hence the inability to find anything. Glad to help, leave a comment (here or there) if you have any questions.