# Web app and USB communication without using NPAPI plugin

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, npapi, browser-plugin

I have NPAPI browser plugin for Chrome,Firefox  for a USB device. This plugin allows silver light web application to communicate with the USB device.

Interaction involve
1.data transfer
2.querying USB device for info
3. and saving data in to USB device.
Recently [Chrome](http://blog.chromium.org/2013/09/saying-goodbye-to-our-old-friend-npapi.html) announced that it  is not gonna support the NPAPI plugin in future.

I have found PPAPI support will be there in chrome but it is not a standard and it will not work on firefox and other browser.Is there other way to achieve without using plugin.
Do we have any other solution for this issue?

Answer (score 1):

For Chrome, [Native Messaging](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html#native-messaging) from an extension (also linked from the blog post you referenced) is likely the best replacement.

As for it being "non standard", in general you probably shouldn't expect anything that's not part of the actual web platform itself to be standard across browsers. (Note that NPAPI isn't really a standard in the formal web sense, and in practice it wasn't standard in the sense of being ubiquitous given that IE has never supported it, and Windows 8 Metro browsers, Chrome OS, all browsers on iOS, and Chrome on Android don't support it either.)

Answer (score 0):

For Firefox, using [js-ctypes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/js-ctypes) from an extension should work for you. Alternatively you could look into mechanisms for communicating with a native application that works cross-browser (e.g. WebSockets? The FireBreath developer mailing list has some recent discussions on this).

Comment: Presently I needed solution for chrome.It would be good if i get cross browser support.Do we have any example for web socket.How it communicate with USB devices.I heard it is only supported in HTML 5.

Comment: The question sounded like you're looking for a solution for both. WebSocket would allow you to communicate with a native app which could do the actual work. In older browsers you should be able to use fallbacks/drop-ins, e.g. Flash-based ones.

Comment: @Thanks George for reply.Will Web Socket supported in older browser I mean in html 4

Comment: You will need relatively new browsers, see e.g. [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/WebSockets#Browser_compatibility). However, older browsers definitely allow plugins, so you can use opaque fallbacks. Check e.g. [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3755531/html5-web-sockets-tcp-connection-with-flash-fallback).